# Entity Framework - Joining approaches - Mixing code-first and database first

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have my domain entities. These entities are all together in a class library. My database already exists and many systems are using it.

I want to use the EDMX just to map which field from my POCO class are which column at the database.

I neither want to generate the database nor the entities again, because they both already exist. I just want the use the EDMX to make the development easier instead of using the fluent api to map (code-first approach).

**UPDATE 1:**

I want just a *DATA MAPPER* feature. I think iBatis is the most near of what I want. Can I achieve the same result with Entity Framework (or nHibernate)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy the .edmx file to your new project, open it, add a code generation item and add the POCO generator for it.

Done. Make sure to add the connection string in your web.config.

EDIT:

Sorry, I misunderstood.  You will need to reverse engineer the database to .edmx file, then set the Code Generation Strategy to None.  Next, you will have to map the namespaces for the classes to your existing domain namespaces, and if there are any differences in Entity names from table names, you will have to specifically map those.

There may be other configurations you have to do as well, but this should get you started.

Comment: Thx, for reply! I don't have an .edmx file and I don't want to generate anything. just to map, class -> table, property -> table column. I tried to figured out, but I always get stucked on generation instead of simple use. I think iBatis works this way, but don't have a .edmx-similar file